# Trigger PropertyChanged of the certain element in collection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, inotifypropertychanged

Having two collections in the `ViewModel`, one is working as a **source of rows** for the `DataGrid` (in this case have only values 1,2,3,..), and other object that represents **sequencer** for one column in the DataGrid (based on ID expose some value in property).

In the example below I have used default `ObservableObject` and  `FullyObservableCollection` behaviour, but it was also tried with other kinds of collections with no success. WPF behavior was tested on both `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and `DataGridTemplateColumn` with `ComboBox`.

---

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private FullyObservableCollection<Seq> mSequencer;
    public FullyObservableCollection<Seq> Sequencer
    {
        get { return mSequencer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mSequencer, value); }
    }

    private FullyObservableCollection<RowSrc> mRowSource;
    public FullyObservableCollection<RowSrc> RowSource
    {
        get { return mRowSource; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mRowSource, value); }
    }
}
```

---

**Class definitions:**

```
public class Seq : ObservableObject
{
    private int mId;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return mId; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mId, value); }
    }

    private string mName;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return mName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mName, value); }
    }
}

public class RowSrc : ObservableObject
{
    private int mValue;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.mValue; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mValue, value); }
    }
}
```

---

**View - XAML:**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Proxy" Source="{Binding Sequencer}"/>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RowSource}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}"
                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                    SelectedValuePath="Id"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

From the above, datagrid is initiliazed with the values of `RowSource`, that will go throught binding tunnel to the `Proxy`, which will lead to `Sequencer`. Based on the `Value` of each row, object with same `Id` will be returned from the `Sequencer` collection.

As is, on the first start everything works well. Problem starts, when we want to empty the Sequencer and fill it again.

```
Sequencer.Clear();
Sequencer.AddRange(...);
```

Now the items in the `Sequencer` refresh, however the binding between `Row[n].Combobox` and the items in Sequencer **DO NOT REFRESH**. The reason behind this is that the properties themselves has not changed, only items in collection.

---

**Workaround - hack:**

```
public class RowSrc
{
    ...

    public void InvokeChange()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    Sequencer.Clear();
    Sequencer = GenerateNewCollection();

    //after update of Sequencer
    foreach (var nRowSrc in RowSrc) nRowSrc.InvokeChange();
}
```

However this means that we would need to add this specific method to each of our Model classes, and then remember to call them on each of Sequencer change.

**Q: How to invoke property change automatically, when the collection changed OR how to handle this binding correctly?**

Comment: `ObservableCollection` just notifies when element is added, removed etc. I want to trigger PropertyChanged of property of element in the collection even though it wasn't changed(even if makes no sense). I'm just curious if it's possible and if it is what should I put as string to my OnPropertyChanged. Hope it does make sense.

Comment: You mean you want to fire the PropertyChanged event without actually changing the property value? For what reason?

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you posted, is very simply, just use an `ObsevrableCollection` instead of a `List`. In fact, `ObsevrableCollection` dose not only report `Add` and `Remove`, it report all kind of movement that support by `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event. So if you use indexer of `ObsevrableCollection` to set an element, a `CollectionChanged` of type `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace` will be raised, and the binding engine will handle it fine from that. But I am a little confused after read you comment, and can not be sure if this is really what you want.

Comment: That's not what I want. As weird as it sounds I want to trigger `PropertyChanged` of the element(in collection) which hasn't been changed. For the reason of making `DataGridComboBoxColumn` do some magic displaying proper value(as described in the edited question).

Comment: @Radim.K Then I suggest you provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example. It's hard to understand what you really want base on what had you  provided

Answer (score 0):

You can raise the PropertyChanged event for your Property `Prop1` through calling `MyList[0].OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Foo.Prop1));`.

There is no need to create a `TriggerPropertyChanged` method.

This works, because in your example `OnPropertyChanged` is public and optionally accepts a string, that describes the property name.